# Square Archimedean Spiral

Tags: random-graphs

I saw somewhere an image of a “spiral of squares,” and I looked online to see how I could graph it myself. I found the Wikipedia page for the Archimedean Spiral and its equation, but that just gives a general spiral. I would like to know if there is a way to convert the Archimedean Spiral into this square spiral, or if I need a different equation. The exact product I am going for is this: https://geo-met-me.deviantart.com/art/Square-Spiral-114824119

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the spiral can be obtained as solution of the [**Four Bags Problem**](http://blog.as.uky.edu/sta695/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/four-bugs.pdf) and it turns out to be a logarithmic spiral.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

instead of looking it like squares visualize it as 4 spirals all of which are made of triangles. those spirals are then called "[spiral of Theodorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_of_Theodorus)" these triangles can be made using the Pythagorean theorem to give the length of the next leg based on the previous triangle

[image: spiral]

the four spiral are then arranged like so according to the Pythagorean theorem
 [image: arrangment]